# Adding new related entities in a single action

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Every riddle has one or more questions, how can add both a Riddle and a Question to that riddle by submitting a single form?

This is RiddlesController Create action code:

```
public ActionResult Create(RiddleViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _db.Riddles.Add(new Models.Riddle
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        Description = model.Description ,
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        User = _db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                    });
                    _db.Questions.Add(new Models.Question
                    {
                        Body = model.FirstQuestionBody,
                        Answer = model.FirstQuestionAnswer,
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        // What should I write here? or is there any better way to accomplish this?
                        Riddle = ????? 
                    });
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

This is Riddle model code:

```
public class Riddle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }    

}
```

This is Question model code:

```
 public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public Riddle Riddle { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName ="datetime2")]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

This is RiddleViewModel code:

```
public class RiddleViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        // Question properties
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string FirstQuestionBody { get; set; }
        public string FirstQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your models code also? don't put image.just paste the code.

Comment: I'm new here, couldn't find how to add code in comments. 1 sec

Comment: @Sampath okay, done.

Comment: can you put the code of your `ViewModel` also?

Comment: and can you put the `Create` methods code also instead of the image.B'cos we cannot `copy/paste` it to our solution.

Comment: @Sampath "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." lol. Is there any way to get rid of this error without adding more details? Because i don't think i should add more.

Comment: just type this is `ViewModel`,this is `Model` like that in between the code snippets.

Comment: @Sampath done, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
_db.Questions.Add(new Models.Question
                    {
                        Body = model.FirstQuestionBody,
                        Answer = model.FirstQuestionAnswer,
                        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Riddle = new Models.Riddle
                                    {
                                     Name = model.Name,
                                     Description = model.Description ,
                                     CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                                     User = _db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
                                    }
                       });

                    _db.SaveChanges();
```